# how to connect postgresql with .NET MAUI

Tags: postgresql, .net-maui

I'm new in developing application using .NET MAUI.
Currently I need to have database to my project, but I don't know how to connect PostgreSQL to .NET MAUI. All tutorial I found more to SQLite.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at  https://www.npgsql.org/